How to find the length of a rectangle formed by drawing a parallelogram's bisectors?
I have just proven that if you draw all bisectors of a parallelogram it will form a rectangle. I was wondering how can we calculate the length and width of the rectangle


What have you tried?

I recommend you use the Pythagorean theorem and similarity of opposing triangles to work toward a solution. To start, BE squared plus AE squared equals AB squared. BB’ minus (BE+HB’)=EH, and so on. Setting up a set of equations with associated variables might lead to a potential solution. It might help to first label segments with new variables (e.g., BE = c). Good luck.

LM || NO
(opposite sides of parallelogram LMNO)
∠L+∠M=180∘
(sum of consecutive interior angles is 180∘)
∠MLS +∠LMS =90∘
In ΔLMS, ∠MLS +∠LMS +∠LSM =180∘
90∘+∠LSM = 180∘
∠LSM = 90∘
Hence, ∠RSP = 90∘ , (vertically opposite angles)
Similarly, ∠SRQ = 90∘, ∠RQP = 90∘
and ∠SPQ = 90∘

Interchange BA with LM and DC with NO

Using your image as a reference, let $AB = CD = a$ and $AD = BC = b$
We can proof $\Delta ABE = \Delta CDG$ (equal angles with one edge of common length), and therefore $BE = DG = a\cos \beta$ and $AE = CG = a\sin\beta$.
Notice that $\overbrace{BA'A} = \overbrace{A'AD} = \alpha$ because $AD$ and $BC$ are parallel. Using the Law of Sines in $\Delta ABA'$:
$$
\frac{BA'}{\sin{\overbrace{BAA'}}} = \frac{BA}{\sin \overbrace{BA'A}} \\
\Rightarrow BA'= \frac{BA}{\sin \overbrace{BA'A}} * {\sin{\overbrace{BAA'}}} = \frac{a}{\sin \alpha } * \sin(90 \deg - \beta) = \frac{a\cos{\beta}}{\sin \alpha}
$$
Similarly
$$
\frac{D'C}{\sin{\overbrace{D'DC}}} = \frac{DC}{\sin  \overbrace{DD'C}} \\
\Rightarrow D'C = \frac{DC \sin \overbrace{D'DC}}{\sin \overbrace{DD'C}} = \frac{a \sin \beta}{\sin \alpha}
$$
And now
$$
BA' + D'C = BD' + D'A' + D'A' + A'C' =   BD' + D'A' + A'C' + D'A' = BC + D'A' 
\Leftrightarrow D'A' = BA' + D'C - BC = \frac{a \cos \beta}{\sin \alpha} + \frac{a \sin \beta}{ \sin \alpha} - b = \frac{a}{\sin \alpha}\sqrt{2} \sin(x + \pi/4) - b = c 
$$ where $c$ is defined as the expression $\frac{a}{\sin \alpha}\sqrt{2} \sin(x + \pi/4) - b$.
Let's call $D'A' = c$ for now since I don't like typing out that whole expression out =)). With that, we obtain:
$$ 
HB' = D'F = c\sin \alpha \\
CH = FA' = c\cos \alpha
$$
And now, we need one more piece, the lengths of BB' and DD' themselves. And this can once again be done with the law of sines.
$$
\frac{AB'}{\sin \beta} = \frac{BB'}{\sin (\alpha + 90 \deg - \beta)} = \frac{BB'}{\cos (\alpha - \beta)} \\
\Rightarrow BB' = \frac{D'C \cos(\alpha - \beta)}{\sin \beta} = \frac{\frac{a \sin \beta}{\sin \alpha} \cos(\alpha - \beta)}{\sin \beta} = \frac{a \sin \beta \cos(\alpha - \beta)}{\sin \alpha \sin \beta} = d
$$
where again we define $d$ as $\frac{a \sin \beta \cos(\alpha - \beta)}{\sin \alpha \sin \beta}$.
And finally, we can calculate
$$
\text{width}  = EH = BB' - BE - HB' = d - a\cos \beta - c\sin \alpha \text{ with } \\ c = \frac{a}{\sin \alpha}\sqrt{2} \sin(x + \pi/4) - b \\ \text{ and } d = \frac{a \sin \beta \cos(\alpha - \beta)}{\sin \alpha \sin \beta}
$$
That's just the width lol. Please tell me if there is any mistakes. I hope this answer isn't too long...
